# How to convert Singapore Onemap Co-ordinate to Google maps co-ordinate system

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api, singapore

I have to fetch few 3000 co-ordinates (I am Geo-coding ) and convert it into Google map co-ordinate system.

Following is the process I am doing

I am calling Mapone.sg API for geo-coding in return it gives me x.y values (I am unable to understand the co-ordinate system ) and which needs to be converted to Google map Co-ordinate system.

If you can give me a right direction to work on it will be nice.

Mehul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of OnMap are you using?  From the OneMap site there is this on version issues:

"Issue with Overlay KML and Coord Converter. To overcome the known issue, it is suggested to use version 1.5 or 2.6 of javascript" (for OneMap v2.3)

Could you also give an example of the coordinates being returned?

Google maps works in decimal degrees and there are many online converters (for example from degrees minutes seconds to dec degrees... e.g.